# Neo4j Querying Data Across Sessions

Tags: java, database, session, neo4j, graph-databases

I am having trouble accessing previously created databases in the embedded Java version of Neo4j. What I'd like to do is open a GraphDatabaseService, add several million relationships (not using BatchInserter, only transactions), and then shut down the last transaction and the connection. This would look something like:

```
public class startNeo4j{ …
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( "data/test/base" );
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    IndexManager index = graphDb.index();
    Index<Node> userIds = index.forNodes("userIds");
    RelationshipIndex follows = index.forRelationships("follows");
```

[ here I input a very large csv (several million relationships), also giving relationship and userId indices ]

```
    tx.finish();
    graphDb.shutdown(); }}
```

What I then need to be able to do is open a new GraphDatabaseService and access all that data I just inserted. I checked with the Neo4j list and they've confirmed that it's possible, but didn't provide any details.

I don't want to recreate the index, but when I try to simply reopen it, I get an error where the index (userIds from above) "cannot be resolved." Ideally, if someone had an outline of what the second set of code would look like that would be great. My non-functional one looks like:

```
public class examineNeo4j{
  public static void main (String[] args){
    GraphDatabaseService graphDb = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase( "data/test/base" );
    Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
    IndexHits<Node> hits_final = userIds.get("userId","12");
    Node testthis = hits_final.getSingle();
```

[ or some other query that I want to run ]

```
    tx.finish();
    graphDb.shutdown();}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You also have to do tx.success(); by default a tx is in a "rollback" state.

```
Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
try {
  // do your work here
  tx.success();
} finally {
  tx.finish();
}
graphdb.shutdown();
```

Please keep also in mind that your tx size shouldn't exceed around 10k operations. So please batch transaction with such a block size.